# calculate distance in xcode using UIAccelerometer

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have confused a little bit. Please help me . I wrote this code .And I am getting distX,distY and distZ .Now I want the final distance using these three.

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    velX += (acceleration.x * intervalDate);
    distX += (velX * intervalDate);

    velY += (acceleration.y * intervalDate);
    distY += (velY * intervalDate);

    velZ += (acceleration.z * intervalDate);
    distZ += (velZ * intervalDate);
}
```

Comment: I am trying the same thing. Can u please tell me what is intervalDate here?

Comment: Just one more thing. If a person run/jog with iphone will it give accurate result on how much distance he travelled?

Comment: In my case It failed vishnu

Comment: Was it anywhere closer to the accurate?

Comment: When I place it on the table it gives the accurate results . But When I run it is giving wrong wrong values

Comment: I read it somewhere that the orientation should not change.... Might that be the reason. Any guidance on how should I calculate distance when a person run with Iphone.

Comment: Ok one last question.The result we get in distance. Its in which unit... meters, cm or Kilometer....?

Answer (score 1):

Easy...

```
distance = sqrt( distX*distX + distY*distY + distZ*distZ );
```

Good luck.

Best, Peter

Comment: He's right. Your values (distX, distY, distZ) form a vector, which it is easy to compute the length of. See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Length) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Last and final question -- Am I calculating the distance correctly (Look at my question)?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, I also did this already, with disappointing results due to the noise in the accelerometer. (And I don't know whether the callback method you are using already subtracts the gravity vector. Check the reference.)